# HazelCast list, partition data loss

Tags: hazelcast

When I have 2 node cluster, list.add(xxx) adds data by splitting it to two different nodes.
eg: **Node-1** - carries 3 instances,
**Node-2** - carries 3 instances, 
When we have a total of 6.

When I perform an abrupt shutdown of any one of the *Node/s*, the data/instance in the node gets lost and only 3 is available.

Is it the nature, or can we tune to get the other 3 also.

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: List is not a distributed data structure. How do you make it happen, that each node carries 3 elements? 2 different lists?

Comment: @noctarius, it automatically spreads across, in the cluster.

Comment: No, a single list in Hazelcast is not distributed. A list will always be owned by a single node (+ a backup somewhere else in the cluster, in your case the other node). Multiple different lists, however, reside on different nodes.

Comment: Can you post some code that demonstrates what you're doing ?

Comment: @NeilStevenson , its just instance.getList(String name) ..
Thanks, but as said it works great with Map, rather than using list in distributed environment like I mentioned above.

Comment: Solved it by substituting list to map